# Is there any useScript hook for react native

Tags: react-native

How to use https://usehooks.com/useScript/ in react native
Or Is there any other way to do in react native

For example I need to use https://pm28k14qlj.codesandbox.io/test-external-script.js
in react native like

TEST_SCRIPT.start()

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a platform like https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push because it supports versioning and error handling.